# How to check the SLA of a webservices

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

We currently deployed our Spring Boot Application in GKE(Google Kubernetes Engine) and we are currently using cloud endpoint to secure our web services. We have 11 web service developed which will be consumed by external clients. Is there any way i check the SLO (times, performance) of a webservice in cloud endpoint or in stackdriver.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check:

- [Spring sleuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth)
- [Jaeger operator](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator)

Jaeger is a opentracing standard and can help understand the values, and sleuth is a tool to integrate with spring, there are several options, you might want also to consider [opencensus](https://opencensus.io/)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to expose metrics from your applications. [Spring Sleuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth) is a great choice if you're using Spring Boot.

Then you need to collect the metrics and visualize them. Google provides a tool for that called [Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/). It can also do metric-based alerts. You can find a sample setup for your use case [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-tracing-demo).

There are other performance monitoring services such as [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/technologies/google-cloud-platform-monitoring/) or [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/).

If you want a self-hosted solution, you can use [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/) which is inspired by an internal Google system called [Dapper](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36356.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Google cloud console UI?  Its "Endpoints" tag should show all services your project is running.